# Getting error 400 in jQuery ajax post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to solve it?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
          var option = {
                method: 'POST', 
                url: 'https://api.hesabfa.com/v1/item/save',
                data: {
                    apiKey: '********',   
                    userId: '********',   
                    password: '********',  
                    item:{                
                        Name: 'name',
                        Barcode: '345345345345',
                        ItemType: 0,
                        Unit: 'k',
                        BuyPrice: 500000,
                        SellPrice: 550000,
                        PurchasesTitle: 'Samsung Galaxy J7',
                        SalesTitle: 'Samsung Galaxy J7',
                        Tag: ''
                    }
                }
            }
            $.ajax(option).done(function(result) {
                if (result.Success)
                  
                var r = result.Result;   
            })
            .fail(function() {
            });
    
</script>
```

Comment: what does the error message say other than 400?

Comment: just 400 in console

Comment: searched and its for bad request

Comment: please check the network tab, what the response says

Comment: {"": ["The input was not valid."]}
"": ["The input was not valid."]
0: "The input was not valid."

Comment: 400 error means your parameters/data do not match the data that the API is expecting.  This could be your usename/password/etc *values* or the property names themselves (eg might be expecting userID).  Without additional information regarding the API, it's impossible for us to tell exactly what's causing the problem.

Comment: it just worked when i test it in postman app

Comment: 400 Bad Request The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing). from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Answer (score 0):

Please check the hesabfa API documentation and required fields, maybe you missed something.